# Quadratic Rational function graph plotting

Tags: functions

I learned how to draw graph for a  rational function with quadratic polynomials in the numerator and/or denominator in which we can easily factorise the numerator and denominator but in this question we can't factorise it and I am unable to figure out how to proceed
$$y = \frac{x^2+2x-11}{2(x-3)}.$$

Comment: HINT: $x^2+2x-11=(x-3)(x+5)+4$.

Comment: Observe that $x^2 + 2x - 11 = x^2 + 2x + 1 - 12 = (x + 1)^2 - 12$.

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by insipidintegrator, you can factor the numerator as $(x-3)(x+5)+4$.
So $\frac{x^2+2x-11}{2(x-3)} = \frac{(x-3)(x+5)+4}{2(x-3)} = \frac{(x-3)(x+5)}{2(x-3)} + \frac{4}{2(x-3)} = \frac{x+5}{2} + \frac{2}{x-3}$, which shows that y is the sum of two functions that are (probably) already familiar to you, $\frac{1}{2}x + 2.5$ and $2 \cdot \frac{1}{x-3}$.
The first is the function of a line, stretched by the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ and shifted $2.5$ units up the y-axis and the second is the function of $\frac{1}{x}$, stretched by the factor $2$ and shifted $3$ units on the x-axis to the right.